# The keydown event does not work on the first time js

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the counter does not want to be updated on the first `keydown`, but event fires.

```js
let counter = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode }) => {
  console.log(keyCode);
  if (keyCode === 32) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0].innerText = counter;
    counter++;
  }
});
```

Comment: if the text inside your `counter` class is initially `0` then you need to move `counter++` above `document.getElements...`

Comment: oh, yeh. that makes sense, my head does not work 

Answer (score 1):

It's because at first you are setting innerText of the element to 0 (your initial value), and then you are updating the value. You can reverse it and do something like this:

```js
let counter = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode }) => {
  console.log(keyCode);
  if (keyCode === 32) {
    counter++;
    document.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0].innerText = counter;
  }
});
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: yes, I didn't notice that for some reason Thanks a lot.